# Toggle icon based on input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a function to check an inputs value to determine the Font Awesome icon to display:

```
function xOrCheck(condition, childNumber) {
    if (condition) {
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(childNumber) i.fa").removeClass("fa-check-circle");
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(childNumber) i.fa").addClass("fa-times-circle");
    } else {
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(childNumber) i.fa").removeClass("fa-times-circle");
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(childNumber) i.fa").addClass("fa-check-circle");
    }
}

$('input#demo').on('focus keyup',function(){
 var value = $(this).val();
 var firstChar = value.substring(0,1);
 xOrCheck(firstChar > 5 , 1);
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<input id="demo" value="4132" />

<ul class="reqs">
  <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Test Item</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Test Item</li>
</ul>
```

I feel like there is a scope issue but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: FYI - you should consider chaining the add and remove to avoid executing the selector multiple times.  example: `$(your_selector).removeClass('fa-check-circle').addClass('fa-times-circle');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your html, add quotes to the value:

```
<input id="demo" value="4132" />

<ul class="reqs">
  <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Test Item</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Test Item</li>
</ul>
```

And in your js, you are not properly using the function parameter:

```
function xOrCheck(condition, childNumber) {
    if (condition) {
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(" + childNumber + ") i.fa").removeClass("fa-check-circle");
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(" + childNumber + ") i.fa").addClass("fa-times-circle");
    } else {
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(" + childNumber + ") i.fa").removeClass("fa-times-circle");
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(" + childNumber + ") i.fa").addClass("fa-check-circle");
    }
}

$('input#demo').on('focus keyup',function(){
 var value = $(this).val();
 var firstChar = value.substring(0,1);
 xOrCheck(firstChar > 5 , 1);
}
```

And you can simplify everything:

```
function xOrCheck(condition, childNumber) {
    var $icon = $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(" + childNumber + ") i.fa");
    if (condition) {
       $icon.removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle");
    } else {
       $icon.removeClass("fa-times-circle").addClass("fa-check-circle");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is JS, not Perl. There's no variable interpolation in strings.

```
function xOrCheck(condition, childNumber) {
    if (condition) {
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(" + childNumber + ") i.fa").removeClass("fa-check-circle");
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(" + childNumber + ") i.fa").addClass("fa-times-circle");
    } else {                   "                 "
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(" + childNumber + ") i.fa").removeClass("fa-times-circle");
       $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(" + childNumber + ") i.fa").addClass("fa-check-circle");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

childNumber argument passed is used wrongly  in your  xOrCheck function  ,hence childNumber is not getting it respective action it should be be as below

```
   $("ul.reqs li:nth-child(" + childNumber + ")
```